# iBooks opening a PDF - "Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm an Objective-C noob trying to open a PDF file in the iBooks library in my app.

I use the following code - it appears to create the open dialog, but I get an error - "Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window." I'm not sure how to correct this...what am I doing wrong here?

```
- (void) showOptionsMenu
{
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"ibooks://test.pdf"];
    docController = [self setupControllerWithURL:fileURL usingDelegate:self];
    bool didShow = [docController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:self.toolbarItems[0] animated:YES];
    if(!didShow)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Sorry, app not found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up fixing the problem by declaring a property for my UIDocumentInteractionController.